# input type text attribute value, make it blank with external css

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have integrated HTML Template to wordpress theme. Now, for search box I dont want value attribute to be displayed. But by default wordpress`s search box displays with that value attribute.

My search box(Wordpress) coding is like below. It is in header.php file

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) : ?>
        <div id="widget-area" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>
        </div><!-- .widget-area -->
    <?php endif; ?>
```

From above coding the search box is generated with that value attribute. How to make it blank with external css. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cant change the actual value with CSS, only javascript or the HTML itself (be it generated with PHP or just static)...

Comment: The search box is coming from the wordpress database. So, I really don`t know how to change it. Is there any wordpress function that can do it? @somethinghere

Comment: I'm not very familiar with wordpress, but a quick google search shows me this, which might help: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/add-search-box-in-header

Comment: Hmm...I think you are right. @somethinghere